# How can I reformat MAC address and IP pairs, ensuring each byte of the MAC has a leading zero?

Tags: string, csv, mac-address

I've got a table like this:

```
10.6.6.12 0:50:56:9b:a6:2

10.6.6.13 fe:9:31:b6:71:1d
```

I must have something like this:

```
10.6.6.12,00:50:56:9b:a6:02

10.6.6.13,fe:09:31:b6:71:1d
```

A `0` is always added before any "lonely" character in the MAC address. I tried the following with bad results:

```
rpl -i ":a:" ":0a:" file.txt
```

Comment: is the 2 -> 20 in the first line a typo?

Comment: @Fiximan If it isn't, he's out of luck since both `02` and `20` are valid hex bytes. I assumed it was a typo and fixed it. If it isn't a typo, he's going to have to explain his broken input a lot better to get a useful answer.

Comment: For the OP: In future, you need to provide a less ambiguous corpus, and post your errors. "Bad results" isn't useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /path/to/table | sed 's/\([ :]\)\([0-9a-f]:*\)/\10\2/g'
```

The above should to the trick.  To explain the expression, the sequence

- `\([ :]\)` - The parens need to be escaped in `sed`; this is a match of either a space or a colon, followed by:
- `\([0-9a-f]:*\)` - a hexadecimal digit followed by zero or more colons, followed by:

Will be replaced by:

- `\1` - The first group (the space or colon)
- `0` - The numeral zero
- `\2` - The second group (the single digit found and the colon if present)

Example use-case:

```
$ echo "1.2.3.4 5:3d:c:12:3" | sed 's/\([ :]\)\([0-9a-f]:*\)/\10\2/g'
1.2.3.4 05:3d:0c:12:03
```

Comment: Looks like they have a comma between the two values in their output as well...

Comment: Addressed by appending `;s/ /,/` to the `sed` statement.

Comment: I wasn't sure (without looking closer at your sed) if it could fit right in to the existing one?

Comment: Indeed it is, by changing it to `sed 's/\([ :]\)\([0-9a-f]:*\)/\10\2/g;s/ /,/'`

Answer (score 0):

### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ARGF.readlines.map do |line|
  if line =~ /^\s*$/
    puts
    next
  end 
  ip, mac = line.split /\s+/
  mac = mac.split(?:).map { |b| b.length != 2 ? ?0 << b : b }.join ?:
  puts [ip, mac].join ?,
end
```

### Results

```
$ ruby /tmp/macfix.rb /tmp/corpus 
10.6.6.12,00:50:56:9b:a6:02

10.6.6.13,fe:09:31:b6:71:1d
```